# Page stalls when trying to compile recursive directives in Angular

Tags: javascript, angularjs, recursion, angularjs-directive

This is my template for comments, notice that `app-comment` is called again, making it nested and recursive:

```
<div>
    <div class="app-comment-main">
        {{ comment.body }}
    </div>
    <ul class="app-comment-replies" ng-hide="comment.replies.length <= 0">
        <li class="app-comment-container" ng-repeat="comment in comment.replies">
            <div class="app-comment" info="comment"></div>
        </li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

This is the directive:

```
(function(global){
    'use strict';

    angular.module('comment-directives', [])

    .directive("appComment", ["$log", function($log) {
        $log.info("Comment!");

        return {
            restrict: "C",
            replace: true,
            comment: "=info",
            templateUrl: "/static/views/directives/comment.html"
        }
    }])

})(this);
```

The page always hangs while trying to compile this, I assume it is stuck in an infinite loop. What am I doing wrong, or how can I do this differently?

Answer (score 0):

Your directive doesn't create a new scope, so it's always iterating over the same replies.

```
        return {
        restrict: "C",
        replace: true,
        scope: { 
          comment: "=info"
        }
```